# I want to paint a pixel in winform faster than the method of FillRectangle

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, pixel

It is possible to paint a pixel by using the `FillRectangle` method by setting the width and height to 1. However, it seems slow when painting 500*600 pixels in a loop by `FillRectangle` method. I searched for alternatives such as `DrawLine` method but this is slow also.

Can anyone offer me a solution?

Best Regards

Comment: Create bitmap, fill it directly by setting pixel values, and draw it in the form. See Bitmap.LockBits Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: There is a fixed overhead to do any kind of painting, whether it to the screen or to a bitmap.  It is pretty small, but when you do this for every single pixel then it adds up O(n^2).  The only way to bypass it is to get a raw pointer to bitmap memory.  No longer practical for the screen like it used to be back in the DOS days, the device driver gets in the way, but still possible for a bitmap.